# How to save visio VSD into EPS?

Tags: eps

I have a sketch saved as .vsd file (made in visio 2007). How do I convert it 
to the .eps format to be used as LaTeX figure?

Comment: This question doesn't belong to this site. Maybe google will help: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=visio+to+eps

Comment: Open it in Visio and export it to EPS. Alternatively print it into a PDF file using a PDF pseudo-printer and use `pdfcrop` to crop it. You won't get far without Visio here.

Comment: fyi, there is no export to EPS option in VISIO.

Answer (score 6):

You could use vsd2svg and Inkscape to turn VSD files into EPS:

```
vsd2svg example.vsd example.svg
inkscape -z -T -E example.eps example.svg
```

vsd2svg is available from http://dia-installer.de/vsd2svg
Inkscape is available from http://inkscape.org

Comment: I have a Visio 2013 and I just tried to save a quite simple diagram (flowchart) as SVG (possible in Visio itself) and then open it in Inkscape. Unfortunately, Inkscape does not show it correctly (captions misplaced etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Save the file as "EMF" -> Enhanced Metafile File in Visio. Visio -> Save As -> Enhanced Metafile File

Then download the metafile2eps.exe from here

http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/MetafileToEPSConverter

Its a nifty piece of software, give the input emf file to it, and export as EPS !
Done !

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked good with a simple flowchart in Visio 2013

Answer (score 2):

Instead of convertion, which often corrupts my drawings, you can print it to EPS.

1. Download PostScript printer driver, e.g. [from Xerox](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/global-printer-driver/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win7x64&fileLanguage=en)
2. Install it (run .exe), the add printer dialog will appear. Select Local Printer, then you will be offered to select printer port, select "FILE: Print to file" as a printer port.
3. Print from Visio to EPS using this printer. While printing you will be asked for a filename, enter something like C:\Users\User\Desktop\file.eps

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save as a PDF, then use [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to convert it into ps

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save as a PDF, then use **Adobe acrobat reader** to convert it into eps.